# How can I create an in memory sqlite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have tried `SQLiteConnection(":memory:")` and `SQLiteConnection("sqlite::memory:")` but both of these fail with *'Invalid ConnectionString format'*

Answer (score 95, accepted):

try

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an exception 'The path is not of a legal form.'

Comment: @Steztric try not putting a space between Data Source => new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:")

Comment: `var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");`

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this:

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = ":memory:" };
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late, but `FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared;` is working.

[It's knowledge from forum question](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Compiling-System-Data-SQLite-with-latest-sqlite3-dll-td63465.html)

Comment: Any more info?  I get `System.ArgumentException : Keyword not supported: 'fulluri'.` using `var connection = new SqliteConnection("FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared;");`

Comment: @Andrez Lowercase `SqliteConneciton` you are using is from different package `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` which doesn't work with FullUri parameter.